# Quasi-independence of "randomized" translations of two sets in the unit cube.

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

The following is an observation  made by Elias Stein in his preparation to proving a maximal inequality (Harmonic Analysis, Elias Stein, pp. 442):

> Suppose $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two subsets of the unit cube $Q\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there is an $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
> $$\begin{align}|A_1\cap(A_2-h)|\geq 2^{-n}|A_1||A_2|\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}$$

Here $|\;|$ stands for Lebesgue measure. The argument he presented is to consider
$$ \eta(x)=\int\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(y)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(x+y)\,dy$$

- It is obvious that $\int \eta(x)\,dx=|A_1||A_2|$, and *clear* that $h$ is supported in the cube $C$ of sides of length $2$ centered at the origin. That much I can see.

**Problem:** The difficulty is his conclusion that (*) implies that there is $h$ in  $C$ such that
$$ \eta(h)=\int\mathbb{1}_{A_1}(y)\mathbb{1}_{A_2}(h+y)\,dy\geq 2^{-n}|A_1||A_2|$$
just like that.

Of course once this is establish then \eqref{one} follows since $\eta(h)=|A_1\cap(A_2-h)|$.
This may be so simple I can't see it. If any one has a clear explanation I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\chi_{A}\ast\chi_{B}$ is continuous for bounded sets $A,B$, so $\eta(x)\leq\max\eta=\eta(h)$ for some $h$, then
\begin{align*}
\eta(h)=\dfrac{1}{|C|}\int_{C}\eta(h)dx\geq 2^{-n}\int_{C}\eta(x)dx=2^{-n}|A_{1}||A_{2}|.
\end{align*}